# Review of Docstring without accompanying code

Tags: discussion

I am working hard to document a small utility I am using as my first Python project.  Would it be appropriate to post the module docstring itself for review without the accompanying wall of code?  I intend to have the code reviewed as well when it's ready, but I want to break it into a few smaller to digest questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would consider that as off-topic, based on the rule that it has to be *real code*. I don't consider documentation alone as code.

Besides, if we don't see the actual implementation of your method, how can we say anything about its documentation?

```
/**
 * Generate a random integer in range 1 to 6.
 * @return Random integer from 1 to 6.
 */
public int randomInt() {
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the feedback I needed and the position  I was assuming (which I hold also after re-reading the site rules again.) Off to read some QA on best practices for posting!

Answer (score 2):

I would consider that off-topic, based on the rule that code posted for review must be working.

Comment: OK, but technically, the code does work.  If you type `help(<module_name>)` the docstring prints.  ;)