# Reviewing Git commit messages alongside code

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Recently, I have started using Git regularly for both my projects at work and my small personal projects. I was wondering if it would be acceptable to request Git commit message reviews alongside the posted code here.

If these types of questions are deemed on-topic, how would you recommend phrasing them appropriately?

I have conducted a search on the CR meta and the following is the only Git-related question that I have found:

[Are Git workflow questions on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/are-git-workflow-questions-on-topic)

Comment: I think commit messages are meta-comments at best. While writing good and clear messages is important, I don't see them overlapping with our scope. They simply are not part of the code/program itself, not more so than documentation or any similar supporting part of your project may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

Our help center's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas:
>
> - Application of best practices and design pattern usage
> - Potential security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> … then you are in the right place!

Additionally we have a number of questions asking for reviews of (close to) human language. All with the answer "no".

- [Questions about documentation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1541)
- [Are questions to review markdown on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5000)
- [Review of Docstring without accompanying code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5131)
- [Can I request that someone look over my legal code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6593)

Finally project structure and git best practices are off-topic:

- [Is reviewing project structure on topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1025)
- [Are Git workflow questions on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1930)